# Python 2.7 Multi-threaded DB-Connection crashes randomly

Tags: python, multithreading, cx-oracle

We use cx_Oracle to connect multiple threads to the database and issue various selects and updates.
However, for unknown reasons, the script is being killed by the system on random database connections. There are no informations in the syslog or messages-files.

Due to the error handling we try to write tracebacks in the logfile. Unfortunately we have no information about the crash of the script in the logfile. Only in stdout is a printout with "PID killed" at the last line.

Could it be a problem to make database connections with multiple threads at the same time? There are also other scripts running at the same time that also talk to the database (not multi-threaded) but access other tables.

This is our Function that is called for every select. For the updates we have other Functions.

```
def ora_send_sql( logger, statement):
    try:
        dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(SQL_IP, SQL_PORT, SQL_SID)
        con = cx_Oracle.connect(SQL_USR, SQL_PWD, dsn)
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(statement)
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        return 0
    except cx_Oracle.Warning as w:
        logger.warning(" Oracle-Warning: "+ str(e).strip())
        pass
    except cx_Oracle.Error as e:
        error, = exc.args
        logger.error(" Oracle-Error-Code:", error.code)
        logger.error(" Oracle-Error-Message:", error.message)
        return -1
    except:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        logger.exception(" Got Traceback in ora_send_sql: " + str(exc_type) + " Fname=" + str(fname) + " Lineno=" + str(exc_tb.tb_lineno))
        return -2
```

Comment: I don't suppose you tried turning `except:` into `except Exception as e` and then trying to see if the exception is somewhat special.
Another possible thing to try perhaps is removing the exception handling completely and letting it crash, then investigating the output. That way you could spot the actual exception that is thrown, because I simply cannot believe it would just "crash".
Finally, try investigating `dmesg` for any segfaults.

Comment: Thanks for your input, i will try this out. Dmesg shows no information about a segfault or something else.   I forgot to mention, that the stdout prints "PID killed" in the last line.

Comment: Well that's an interesting thing. I don't suppose you are able to investigate the memory at the time of the killing? This "PID killed" message (if it was not done by a user) could mean that the kernel killed the application because of resource starvation

Comment: I created a script which executes 16 parallel Updates on a Oracle-DB to reproduce the error. I tried all of your tips but only got "Killed" at stdout. No Exceptions or something else.... The Kill actually happens randomly at a update of the script.

Comment: It seems that the kernel is shutting down (killing) your scripts. Just to confirm: You monitored memory (RAM, disk) and swap usage?

Comment: Yes we are monitoring memory and swap usage. Actually there are 6 GB of free RAM available and nothing is swaped. Also there is more than enough disk space available. The system-load is also pretty low. The only thing to mention is that there are 10 Gigs of cached RAM

Comment: Hm, have you tried looking at `/var/log/kern.log`  file?

Comment: Actually there is no information in this log-file. Its getting weird

Comment: Hm. Right, how about this: add `print("different string each line")` after each line within the try clause. That way at least you could spot the _exact_ spot where the script stops and if it is the same spot every time. I think running the 16 parallel updates again should definately help bring some ideas.

Comment: we actually fixed it by updating cx_Oracle :)

Comment: Well done :)) Although the problem left me curious :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we have fixed the problem by updating cx_Oracle to the latest version. 
They fixed a few memory-leaks in the updates.....

But that still does not explain why we do not see any information about the killing....

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose you tried turning except: into except Exception as e and then trying to see if the exception is somewhat special. Another possible thing to try perhaps is removing the exception handling completely and letting it crash, then investigating the output. That way you could spot the actual exception that is thrown, because I simply cannot believe it would just "crash". Finally, try investigating dmesg for any segfaults.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly need to use `threaded=True` in the `connect()` call, see http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#cx_Oracle.Connection